# Which Storage Limit does a ContentNote count against?

Tags: contentnote

While we can query a ContentNote with SOQL, it does not appear that ContentNote "records" count against Data Storage the way a proper sObject does.

I believe a ContentNote counts towards File Storage but I don't see this documented explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced Notes count towards File Storage and can be [inferred](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) from documentation...

> ContentNote is built on ContentVersion